# Get inner data format from MONGO DB

Tags: mongodb, nested

I have collection of data in my MongoDB and I would like to get it in special grouped and sorted nested object because then I need to iterate over it. First it should group into object by date, then the same
dates should group by country. Finally, they should be sorted by number of posts ASC.

Collection in DB:

```
    /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5398c7d879b103fc9dfcaf"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "Germany",
    "posts" : 10
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5398c7d879b103fc9dfcae"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "France",
    "posts" : 7
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5398c7d879b103fc9dfcdd"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "USA",
    "posts" : 5
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5398c7d879b103fc9dfcea"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "Germany",
    "posts" : 4
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5398c7d879b103fc9dfcbf"),
    "date" : ISODate("2020-02-27T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "country" : "Japan",
    "posts" : 2
}
```

I would like to get following output:

```
[ ISODate("2020-02-26T00:00:00.000Z") : {
    [ Germany : { [4, 10]},
      USA: { [5] }
    ]

},
ISODate("2020-02-27T00:00:00.000Z") : {
    [ France : { [7]},
      Japan : { [2] }]
}
]
```

I want to emphasize I don't want sum of posts for every country in the most inner array, but mention all post values.
I tried to use aggregation with $group and $sort, but can't get nested elements in required output.

Comment: Do you really like to use the country as field name? Having a **Date** as field name could be a real challenge - I don't think that's possible.

Comment: This is as close as I could get: [mongodb](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G8y_Zh0MsJs) I'll be interested to see how this is done though. I know it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can get close.

A key may not be of type ISODate, but we can project that as a string.

First, group by date+country to add up the count for each country for each day.
Then group by date to collect the country records for each day, appending them to an array with each in the form `{"k":country_name, "v": post_count}`
Last, create the final document using arrayToObject.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: {date: "$date",country: "$country"},
      posts: {$sum: "$posts"}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.date",
      data: {
        $push: {k: "$_id.country",v: "$posts"}
  }}},
  {$replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [[
            {k:{$dateToString: {date: "$_id"}},
             v:{$arrayToObject: "$data"}
            }
        ]]
  }}}
])
```

The output should look something like:

```
[{"2020-02-26T00:00:00.000Z": {
      "Germany": 14,
      "USA": 5
 }},
 {"2020-02-27T00:00:00.000Z": {
      "France": 7,
      "Japan": 2
 }}
]
```

Check out the available date [format specifiers](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html#format-specifiers) if you need that date to look differently.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MAVjx8aSCbG)